# save unlocked character in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a code in which when you click on a button and you have enough coins, it must be unlocked and a piece of wood with price on it that acts like a lock must be disappear. Every thing works fine, but when I restart the game, every thing returns to default. I'm new to unity and I want to use Playerprefs but I don't know how exactly. here is my script;

```
  using System.Collections;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using UnityEngine;
        using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
        using UnityEngine.UI;

        public class MainMenu3 : MonoBehaviour {
        public Button WhitePlane;
        public Button BluePlane;
        public static int character_number;

        public GameObject wood1;
        public GameObject wood2;

        void Start () {

        character_number = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("Number");
        BluePlane.onClick.AddListener (() => {
        character_number=1;
        if (UIManager2.coin_score>=1) {
        UIManager2.coin_score--;
        wood1.setactive (false);

        SceneManager.LoadScene ("Menu2");
                    }

                });

       WhitePlane.onClick.AddListener (() => {
        character_number=2;
        if (UIManager2.coin_score>=2){

        UIManager2.coin_score--;
        UIManager2.coin_score--;
        wood2.setactive(false);

        SceneManager.LoadScene ("Menu2");
                                  }
                    });
    void Update () {
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("Number", character_number);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see from this code when the callbacks are triggered.

You can try:
Try this in build. Not just from the Editor.
Add debug prints using UnityEngine.Debug.Log() whenever the values changes, and also send it to prefs from there.

(Saving it every Update() is sort of misusing the interface).

The Unity doc shows where the values are stored. Check if they arrived there. For example on Windows it is a Registry path

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html